# Do While loops, but only returns the first specified value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a novice programmer and I'm making a program that will send individualized emails to merchandisers with a list when they've violated our pricing policies. I've gotten sending the email and filling in most of the merchandiser-specific information to work, but I'm trying to include URL links so they can view their violations in detail.

Different merchants will have different numbers of violations, so I added this while loop at the end so it adds only those URLs that are pertinent to them. This loop is nested inside a For loop to the end of the data.

```
Do While ((Range("B" & n).Value <> "") And (Range("A" & n).Value = ""))
   xMsg = xMsg & xRg.Cells(n, 21) & vbCrLf
   n = n + 1
Loop
```

If the value in B row n is not empty and A row n is it should add the URL from column 21 on row n to the bottom of the message and then stop when those conditions aren't met (when we're at a new merchant).

Currently, it will only return the value for column 21 from the first row and nothing else, despite appearing to loop.

I've ran the debugger to see if the loop isn't incrementing like it should, but that seems to be working. I've also tried formatting it as a Do Until Loop, using Cells(n, 1).Value and Cells(n, 2).Value for the reference addresses and a Do While with one of the conditions and a nested If to create the other. Nothing has worked.

I can include more of my code if that would be helpful. Please excuse any sloppiness in my code (I know there are plenty). I'm an accountant, not a programmer.

Here is the entirety of my code. Full disclosure and in the interest of plagarism, I got the majority of it from Kutools on Extendoffice.com and have just modified it to my needs. I've also edited out the actual text of the email body.

```
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                     ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                     ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                     ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
  Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                     ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                     ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                     ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
#End If
Sub SendEMail()
'update by Extendoffice 20160506
Dim xEmail As String
Dim xSubj As String
Dim xMsg As String
Dim xURL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Long
Dim k As Double
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xTxt As String

On Error Resume Next
xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If xRg.Columns.Count <> 21 Then
    MsgBox " Regional format error, please check", , "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
End If
For i = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
            n = i + 2
        If InStr(1, xRg.Cells(i, 13).Value, "@") > 0 Then
'               Get the email address
            xEmail = xRg.Cells(i, 13)
'               Message subject
            xSubj = "MAPP Violation"
'               Compose the message
            xMsg = ""
            xMsg = xMsg & "Text" &vbCrLf
Do While ((Range("B" & n).Value <> "") And (Range("A" & n).Value = ""))
                    xMsg = xMsg & xRg.Cells(n, 21) & vbCrLf
                    n = n + 1
                Loop
                
'       Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
    xSubj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xSubj, " ", "%20")
    xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, " ", "%20")
'       Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
    xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")
'       Create the URL
    xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg
'       Execute the URL (start the email client)
    ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, xURL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
'       Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Application.SendKeys "%s"
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Again, I apologize for the sloppiness. I know the formatting is mediocre and I can make the Do While Loop as a separate sub and call it. I learned basic C++ five years ago and haven't retained much of my knowledge or etiquette. I wasn't planning on anyone else seeing my code so I wasn't going to clean it up until I got it working.

Currently, it's set up so you select the total data range for it to look at. I've kept it that way so I could test it without sending tons of emails to unsuspecting victims. Once I have it working I'll change xRg to be the last populated row and column.

Here's what the data I'm using looks like. I've edited the merchant information to protect their privacy.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7ipn.jpg)

Comment: It would be useful to include more code here.   You're using `Range()` and `xRg.Cells()` to access cell values, but it's unclear how those are related.  What does `xRg` refer to?

Comment: I've added the rest of my code. xRg refers to the total range of cells that the sub will get data from. I'm using xRg.Cells() and Range() to reference cell addresses and their corresponding values within that wider scope.

Comment: When you run this what range are you selecting?  What do you get from `Debug.Print xRg.Address`  for example?  It's not clear what your data looks like, or why (eg) you use `n = i + 2`  and then switch to accessing cell values using `Range()` instead of `xRg.Cells()`

Comment: It's difficult to make sense of the screenshot without the column and row headers, and you also still need to mention what range you're selecting when running this.  What is the value of `xRg.Address` and what is the range shown in your screenshot?

Comment: I've added an image of what my my spreadsheet looks like. Right now I use a small range of cells so I can control how many emails I'm sending. I changed the vendor email associated with that small range to my work one so I don't inundate them with tons of useless emails while I'm testing. I use ```n = i + 2``` because relevant data doesn't start until two lines after the email address is found. I also switched to ```Range()``` as part of my troubleshooting. I've changed it back to ```xRg.Cells()```. ```Debug.Print``` shows the selected range--$A$2:$U:$9 in this case.

Comment: Seems like you need `Do While xRg.Cells(n, "B").Value <> "" And (xRg.Cells(n, "A").Value = ""`   Just work with xRg instead of xRg and the whole sheet (which is what you're accessing when using just `Range()`)

Comment: I changed it and no dice. I changed the values in the cells containing URLs to numbers (1,2,3, etc.) and it would append all of the numbers and the first URL, no URLs after that.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested fix:

```vb
Sub SendEMail()

    Dim xEmail As String, xSubj As String, xMsg As String, xURL As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, k As Double
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", _
                                   "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If xRg.Columns.Count <> 21 Then
        MsgBox " Regional format error, please check", , "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
        If InStr(1, xRg.Cells(i, 13).Value, "@") > 0 Then
            xEmail = xRg.Cells(i, 13) 'Get the email address
            xSubj = "MAPP Violation" 'Message subject
            xMsg = "Text" & vbCrLf
            n = i + 2

            '### use xRg.Cells() not Range() here...
            Do While xRg.Cells(n, "B").Value <> "" And xRg.Cells(n, "A").Value = ""
                xMsg = xMsg & xRg.Cells(n, 21) & vbCrLf
                n = n + 1
            Loop
                    
            xSubj = Replace(xSubj, " ", "%20") 'Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
            xMsg = Replace(xMsg, " ", "%20")
            xMsg = Replace(xMsg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A") 'Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
            xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg 'Create the URL
            
            'Execute the URL (start the email client)
            ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, xURL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
            'Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
            Application.SendKeys "%s"
            
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It's still only including the first URL. I thought it might be the email app I'm using, so I switched to a different one and it still only included the first link. I ran ```debug.print xMsg``` at various locations (in the loop, after, as it's replacing spaces with the Hex) it all shows it's in there. You've been a great help, Tim, but unless you can think of a reason it would shorten the message while it's sending it I think the problem's with my email provider or service.

Comment: Are you willing to share your workbook via email (redacted as needed, but still with the issue you describe)?

Comment: Yes. I'm a first-time poster. Is there a best way to share it? Depending on the method I may have to get approval, but I can get it done.

Comment: I'm sorry Tim, I was waiting for approval that never came and I ended up solving it.

Comment: No problem - glad you got a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

My issue seems to have been a that the URLs were too long and I reached a character limit which caused errors when exporting to Outlook. I ended up rewriting my code in HTML format so I could add the URLs as hyperlinks and that worked.